# Numbering objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
let _arr =[{obj_num: 1.1}, {obj_num: 1.5}, {obj_num: 4}, {obj_num: 3.1}, {obj_num: 3.3}];
```

I need to order their numbers based on both sides of the decimal, ie:

```
let _arr =[{obj_num: 1.1}, {obj_num: 1.2}, {obj_num: 2}, {obj_num: 3.1}, {obj_num: 3.2}];
```

Objects are grouped byt the first number in the decimal: So 1.1 & 1.2 belong to object group 1.

Objects with no decimal point in the `obj_num` are within their own group.

The objects need to be numbered in acsending order according to their group.

So if obj_num: 1.1, and obj_num: 1.3 belong to group 1, they should become 1.1 and 1.2.

If obj number 1.1, 1.3, 2, 4.3 were in order, they would need to become 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3.1.

I am stumped and think that i'm making a mountain out of a molehill.

What I am trying right now:

```
this.data.questions =[{question_num: 1.1}, {question_num: 1.5}, {question_num: 4}, {question_num: 3.1}, {question_num: 3.3}];
let _normalQuestionRef = 0;
let _questionRef = {
    totalObjs: _arr.length,
    objects: {},
};

// Create a reference object that groups questions by the number before the decimal
this.data.questions.forEach((_q, _i) => {
    let _qNum = _q.question_num.split('.')[0];
    _questionRef.questions[`question_${_qNum}`] = _questionRef.questions[`question_${_qNum}`] || [];
    _questionRef.questions[`question_${_qNum}`].push({
        index: _i,
        q: _q,
    });
});

// Re-populate the original array
Object.keys(_questionRef.questions).forEach((_qRef) => {
    let _qSet = _questionRef.questions[_qRef];

    // Increment the base question number
    _normalQuestionRef ++;

    // If there are questions with a decimal point number
    if (_qSet.length > 1) {

        // Loop each decimal point and place it in the specified index of the array
        _qSet.forEach((_q, i) => {
            _q.q.question_num = _normalQuestionRef + '.' + String(i + 1);
            this.data.questions[_q.index] = _q;
        });
    } else {
        // Just add it as is
        _qSet[0].q.question_num = _normalQuestionRef;
        this.data.questions[_qSet[0].index] = _qSet[0].q;
    };
});
```

But it's not quite there. Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean sort by both sides of a decimal? You mean *numerically*?

Comment: @Jordão - my mistake, i've corrected the answer - and the objects are truncated for readability.

Comment: @AndrewLi - It's not so much a case or sorting, but re-numbering based on their positions in the array

Comment: @AndrewLi Consider the first array one that has had object removed, new identifiers need to be calcuated as represented in the second

Comment: Is the question not clear enough?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty unclear. Does "I need to order their numbers based on both sides of the decimal" mean "I need to sort `_arr` *numerically* by the `obj_num` attribute of its elements"? And why is the title "Numbering objects in an array of objects" when you actually want to sort?

Comment: @le_m I've updated the question to try and make it more clear -

Comment: What is the expected result when obj_num's are `[-1.1, 0, 1, 1.1, 5, 1.2, 1]`?

Comment: @le_m it's quite clearly stated in the first two variables in the question

Comment: @SinanGuclu Sorry, your problem is under-specified. The first two variables (I assume the _arr example) do not give any insight into how to renumber the obj_nums I just gave you in above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the last value, the new group value and the offset inside of the group.

```js
var array = [1.1, 1.5, 4, 3.1, 3.3],
    result = array.map(((last, group, offset) => a => {
        offset += 0.1;
        if (Math.floor(last) !== Math.floor(a)) {
            group++;
            offset = a === Math.floor(a) ? 0 : 0.1;
        }
        last = a;
        return group + offset;
    })(0, 0, 0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The reduce master strikes again - thanks this is just what i was looking for

Comment: Reduce is beautiful, you can express almost any transformation imaginable in terms of it.